# What to use instead of substr for this string reformater?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, tokenize, substr

So my professor told me that I had to redo my code because I used substr function in my code in order to complete it. This code uses a function to reformat a user inputed date like **5th Oct 2017** into **2017-02-05**. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get around using substr for this c++ program? Any help is greatly appreciated with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

string reformatDate(string oldDate) {
    string finalDate;
    int d = 0;
    int m;
    int y = 0;
    string month[12] =  {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < oldDate.length(); i++) {
        if(oldDate[i] >= '0' && oldDate[i] <= '9') {
            d = d*10 + oldDate[i] - '0';
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    i = i+3;
    for(m = 1; m <=12; m++) {
        if(month[m-1].compare(oldDate.substr(i,3)) == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    for(i=i+4; i<oldDate.length(); i++) {
        if((oldDate[i] >= '0') && (oldDate[i] <= '9')) {
            y = y*10+ oldDate[i] - '0';
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    char str[20];
    sprintf(str, "%d-%02d-%02d", y, m, d); // formats date into YYYY-MM-DD format
    finalDate = finalDate + str;
    return finalDate;
}

int main() {
    string s;
    cout << "Enter date: ";
    getline(cin, s);

    cout << "Reformated Date: " << reformatDate(s) << endl;
}
```

As you can see I only really use substr once and it would be a pain to have to redo this whole thing because of this one line. So what I need is a workaround in order to make this same code work without substr. Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to answer these questions. Without knowing the reason why a function is forbidden, it's easy to come up with a solution that's just as unacceptable. "Because the prof said so" is terribly hard to deal with. For example, you can try to use [constructor #3](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) which essentially does the exact same thing as `substr`. `std::string(oldDate, 1, 3)` is the same as `oldDate.substr(1, 3)`. Is that going to be accepted? Who knows.

Comment: You can also make your own substring function. It's trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple way for someone who does not know many functions...
Of course can be done easier but I think your professor wants to test you in such simple methods... Good luck!

```
i = i+1;
int k;
int count;
for(m = 1; m <=12; m++) {
  for(k=0; k<3;k++) {
      if(month[m-1][k] == oldDate[i+k]) {
          count++;
      }
   }
   if (count==3)
      break;
   else
       count=0;

}
```

Comment: thank you this helped me answer the problem i was having. This makes more sense to me too

Answer (score 0):

Write your own method that achieves the same functionality as [`string::substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/).

Here is my take, but I encourage you to try writing one too, that's why your professor told you to rewrite the code =)

```
std::string mysubstr(std::string& str, size_t pos, size_t len)
{
    std::string sub_str = "";
    for(size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(i == pos)
        {
            for(size_t j = 0; j < len; ++j)
                sub_str += str[i++];
            break;
        }
    }
    return sub_str;
}
```

It could be used in your code, like this:

```
if(month[m-1].compare(mysubstr(oldDate, i, 3)) == 0)
```

or like this:

```
if(month[m-1] == mysubstr(oldDate, i, 3))
```

and produce the same exact output, for the given input.